# How to change the position of a column in the TYPO3 TCA?

Tags: typo3

I want to move a column from one tab to another. Is there a better way than to rewrite the `types` definition manually which is not very reliant in regard to extension updates changing the TCA?

Comment: Maybe EXT:tcabuilder can help you with that: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/tcabuilder/

Comment: Looks good - but it not installable! Even if I upload the extension manually I get an disturbing "Extension not available" message !?! It is even not listed in the Extension list of the Extension Manager. Wow!

Comment: You could download it also here: https://git.spooner.io/spooner-web/tcabuilder/-/tags
but I suspect that the problems you encountered have been of temporary nature and you could try it again.

Comment: Just released version 2.1.1 which should be working now.

Comment: Yes, this version is installable. But: It does not solve my problem. But the question as I asked it is solvable with tcabuilder.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% fail safe, since there still might be extensions messing things up, but the closest you can get will be to make use of the `ExtTablesInclusionPostProcessing` event and put `addToAllTCAtypes` into the invoke method, since this will not just add new fields but even put existing fields to another tab:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Extension\EventListener;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility;

/**
 * Class ExtTablesInclusionPostProcessing
 */
class ExtTablesInclusionPostProcessing
{
    /**
     * Function which may process data created / registered by extTables
     * scripts (f.e. modifying TCA data of all extensions)
     *
     * @param AfterTcaCompilationEvent $event
     */
    public function __invoke(AfterTcaCompilationEvent $event): void
    {
        ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('tt_content', 'fieldname', '', 'after:fieldname_in_the_other_tab');
    }
}
```

To remove the existing field before, you could make use of this trick:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59179916/2333754

And finally to be on the safer side you could make sure that other extensions are loaded before your own extension by putting them into the `suggest` section of your `composer.json`.

Answer (score 0):

With installation of extension `tcabuilder` it is possible to do simple changes in the TCA.